# How to get the last migration

Tags: django

In django, we can write '__first__' to specify the first migration dependency

```
dependencies = [
    ('auth', '__first__'),
]
```

Is there a way to get the last? 

Something like '__last__' ?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Hello Daniel, thanks for asking.  I'm translating permissions and content types using 'django-modeltranslation' but it creates auto migrations on 'auth' . Since I have my own 'User' and 'Group' extending from 'auth' models,  I need to add the last 'auth' migration on my apps 'dependencies'. Now, this migration names are generated, so i always have to go to the auth migrations folder and rename them. Managing develop and production servers becomes hard and something like '__last__'  would be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is.

It's [name](https://github.com/django/django/commit/9a2ab629776735fae2c9184dc4b9d9029bad15b2) is `__latest__`.

Example:

```
dependencies = [
    ('auth', '__latest__'),
]
```

Comment: Can you please add a reference to this in documentation or code?

Comment: Currently there is not [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/search/?q=__latest__) about that. but you can [find](https://github.com/django/django/commit/9a2ab629776735fae2c9184dc4b9d9029bad15b2) [some](https://github.com/django/django/pull/6254) [code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/migrations/loader.py#L142) for that.